# using a macro to create a loop in C

Tags: c, macros

While looking on some legacy code, I found a rather unusual construction (for me at least):

```
#define loop(i,start,stop) for((i)=(start);(i)<(stop);(i)++)
```

This macro is then used everywhere instead of regular **for** loops construction.

I think it's a bad idea in general because it does not really solve a problem nor simplify anything, but can it be **dangerous**? 
By dangerous I mean breaking compilation (best case) or (much worse but more interesting) do something else than expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard cautionary tale against macros is arguments with side effects:

```
loop(i, x, y++)
```

Comment: doesn't macro expansion occur at source level? being so, there are no dangerous side effects *a priori*, it depends "where" the macro uses that argument.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Of course. That's why I applied post-increment to the third argument rather than the second.

Comment: I would suggest macros must come with an "usage contract" that if broken, remove responsibility from the macro-writer:)

Comment: Maybe, but that simply underscores the original premise that macros are dangerous.

Comment: PoV... I would say the opposite: macro are not dangerous, unless you use them badly... Almost the same can be said for function; e.g. there are surely implementation where free(NULL) is "dangerous", while it could fail silently instead. Whoever uses free in that implementation, should know it has to "guard" free with something like if (p != NULL) free(p); something similar could be applied to macros.

Comment: An implementation of `free` that fails on `free(NULL)` is not dangerous; it's broken. The C standard requires that calls to `free(NULL)` have no effect. Macros look like functions, but don't behave like them. This results in subtle bugs that are difficult to spot; hence they are dangerous, just like a hand-grenade is a dangerous device, irrespective of how carefully one handles it. Compare, for example, the C macro `max` to the C++ inline function `max`.

Comment: ok I picked the bad example, I should have used a_function(void *).

Comment: My point remains. Macros are dangerous in ways that functions aren't. If you use them carefully, good for you. The fact that you have to be careful when using them means they're dangerous. To call them anything else is just splitting hairs.

Comment: PoV(2)and semantic.Funcs can be badly used,you need to carefully respect rules in order to use them; e.g. you have to pass the right args and use their results properly. So, if you respect rules, macros are not dangerous. If you do not, macro can be dangerous. If you respect rules, functions are not dangerous. If you do not,they can be dangerous.The set of rules to take into account is different,but in general we don't need to be really so much careful;we already use (potentially)macros: va_*, assert, NULL,offsetof,isdigit,getc(har)...

Comment: @Shin But there's hardly any reason to use eg an assert macro instead of an inlined assert function - macros have some uses but as replacement for functions they're just an anachronism from the last century. And replacing control flow with macros is a horrible idea for anyone having to understand the code - thank you I know C, I don't want to learn yet another language ~

Comment: @Voo I suppose you do not choose, you pick whatever assert.h gives you; if assert is a macro you will use that macro (and assert is, afaik); va_* are macro as well, and offsetof and ... moreover inline func are not in all C std one could care of, so sometimes there's no other way. You don't need to learn another lang. The point was: are really macros so dangerous and what does it mean they need "care"? Your PoV is yes since you need special care. My PoV is no,you use them following exact rules that keep you safe, as other funcs or maybe-funcs (not to talk about other lang features)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: `assert` is just another example that serves my purpose: it is a common source of errors for newer programmers, who inadvertently inject side effects into their arguments. These bugs are particularly insidious, since they only appear in production code, which is heavily optimised and often stripped of debug symbols, both of which make debugging much harder. And no, you do not use exactly the same rules; most functions are perfectly well-behaved in the presence of arguments with side-effects, while macros usually aren't. Look up the definition of "dangerous" in a dictionary.

Comment: ...Just to be clear, I'm not arguing against the use of macros. It's difficult to imagine a useful implementation of `assert` that doesn't rely on them. But you can't extrapolate from usefulness to safety. Hand-grenades can be extremely useful in certain contexts, but that doesn't mean they're safe.

Comment: I understand your point, but I disagree on the judgement of what can be dangerous. Respecting rules on their usage, they are both useful (not in the OP example of course!) and not more dangerous than using simply functions and e.g. not taking into account side effects and sequence points.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Anything can be classified as not-dangerous by not taking the hazards into account. You are beating a dead horse.

Comment: Going into philosophy, it is the opposite: anything can be classified as dangerous by not taking into account rules. E.g. drinking water is dangerous (if you laugh while you drink), walking along a road is dangerous (if you do not walk on the sidewalk), repairing an electronic device is dangerous (if you forget to unplug it) and so on.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: If your last statement and my last statement were mutually exclusive, then you might be on to something.

Comment: I can say the same... (...) then *you* might be on to something. PoV (third time I wrote this, it seems uselessly)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: You've missed the point. Drinking water *is* dangerous for humans, due to the structure of our larynx; people have died doing it. So is walking on the road and doing home electrical repairs. Likewise, macros are dangerous, and nothing you've said about PoV makes an iota of difference. Macros present hazards that functions don't. It's that simple.

Comment: PoV(4),and more than iota.Passing args to funcs is dangerous.Calling a functions(here instead of there e.g.)can be dangerous.Things must be used properly to be not dangerous,otherwise they are *all* dangerous,functions too.Broken usage of nasty side-effects can affect func calls as well.Badly written funcs are dangerous as badly written macros.Literal substitution can produce bad syntax(error at compile time)or good syntax but dangerous legitimate code that *you can write by yourself* without the usage of any macro.Programming languages are dangerous if you use them improperly.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: I don't know how to put it any clearer than my previous statements: "most functions are perfectly well-behaved in the presence of arguments with side-effects, while macros usually aren't," and, " Macros present hazards that functions don't." If you disagree with these, please elucidate. Otherwise, I'll just leave you to your PoV.

Comment: I'm saying that the way you consider macros is a PoV that needs not to be necessarily shared.You implicitly put the stress on the fact that,in your opinion,it is likely that macros are badly written and badly used;I say every lang feature can be misused and thus be dangerous and that respecting rules(as normally do)makes everything usable safely...If side-effects are your concern,the rule "do not put <side-effects> in macro arguments"fix it.You already have a lot of these rules e.g. just to avoid unspecified and undefined behaviours according to C std.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: You are right. Any non-trivial subject allows multiple PoVs. Some people scoff at the notion that hand-grenades are dangerous, arguing that if you respect the rules for safe-handling, everything is fine. Most, however, would say that any object designed to blow you apart is dangerous, period. In my PoV, an experienced and responsible programmer thinks of macros as dangerous, and avoids them where practicable. It obviously isn't as clear-cut for macros as for hand-grenades, so you are entitled to your PoV. But I'll also add that, from my PoV, your PoV leads to much suffering.

Comment: Incidentally, I never stated (or tried to imply) that macros are likely to be badly written. As a matter of fact, they are likely to be badly written, but I deliberately avoid making this point because one of the reasons I consider them dangerous is that even well-written macros can present hazards to unsuspecting users.

Comment: Only badly written macros can be intrinsically dangerous,and wrong usage of well written macros can be dangerous too;hence the deduction that lead me to say you're implicitly saying that.C itself presents hazards to unsuspecting users,that is not present in other langs.It's a"tool".You must learn how to use it correctly.My PoV does not foster the inappropriate use of(absurd)macros,so I can't see how it can lead to much suffering;my PoV is that macros are tools that properly used are not dangerous,and that this statement is generally true for what you wouldn't label as dangerous as macros.>>

Comment: << hand-granades are created to do harm and you can't use them in other ways, so they are dangerous by design. Macros were created to be useful, though they can misused. A better analogy could have been with a knife (not a war knife, I mean a kitchen knife), created to cut bread, not to saw arms.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: OK, let's talk knives. We store our steak- and bread-knives on a magnetic strip. The strip is mounted high up, so that our younger children can't reach them, on a section of the wall that is above the kitchen bench, in case they fall. Why do you think we do that?

Comment: you do that. When I was a child, I could have reached knives as easily as opening a drawer (and even easier when they were left on the table). Never hurted myself or anyone else. Why do you think it is not happened, though I was able to reach knives so easily?

Comment: @ShinTakezou: If you refuse to acknowledge that knives are dangerous — something that probably 99.9% of adults on this planet consider to be a truism — then I abandon all hope of ever convincing you that macros are dangerous. You win.

Comment: the problem is this!you have not to convince me;you have to accept the fact that there are PoV where knives are not dangerous *per se*(if they were,I would be dead or wounded 99.9%),they are dangerous just because they can be used to do harm(though kitchen knives are created to cut bread or whatever)or in the wrong way in general(e.g. resulting in a bloody finger);but if one follows some rule while using them,they will be safe as anything else(and anything else can be dangerous if used dangerously, e.g. a brick can crash heads).

Comment: and it was not a war so there's no winner no looser; I've just notified that *a priori* macros are not dangerous, if you write them and use them properly. In the discussion,I also stressed the fact that we already need to follow rules to make even functions safe; there a lot of errors we can do and that will be noticed at runtime;"we" usually don't,since we respect some "C" rules; about side effects, e.g., "we" know we can't do aFunction(++i, ++i) and also writing aFunction(&i, &i) may be dangerous depending on how the func is written (a real example could be memcpy with dest overlapping src)

Comment: @ShinTakezo: This is my last attempt to get you to see reason; life is too short to spend so much energy trying to convince people who refuse to see the obvious. When I say knives are dangerous, most people would heartily agree (I suppose I could do a straw-poll, but I'm certain enough of the outcome that I won't bother). This is because in a normal commonsense interpretation, the term "dangerous" is taken to mean, "able or likely to cause harm". It isn't an absolute *a priori* statement about the object in question, but rather an injunction to exercise care when wielding said object. ...

Comment: ... Everyone knows that knives can be handled safely. That's not what people mean when they say, "Knives are dangerous." By your definition, in contrast, virtually nothing dangerous exists; neither bare 240 V wires, nor chainsaws, nor arsenic, nor forest fires, nor taipans, nor plutonium rods. It is simply absurd to suggest that anything that *can* be handled properly is not dangerous. Pretty much anyone who knows the pitfalls of macros and the due respect they must accorded when using them will understand and agree with the intended meaning of, "Macros are dangerous."

Comment: you missed the counterargument:everything *is* dangerous,indeed."Able or likely to cause harm" can be applied to bricks and C functions.It depends a subjective demarcation line,movable according to "boundary conditions".240V wires are not dangerous if they are isolated,they are dangerous when they are bare(and so you have 240V wires in you house,since it is safe to keep them like that);already said that,summarizing:**rules**.If you respect them,you can safely use 240V wires,chainsaws,handle arsenic,controlled fires,nuclear plants.This means there's a way to "use"all those things"safely";...

Comment: ...and this is true for macros too, if you are ready to pay the "cost" to use them "with care"(to use your own word).Then,my PoV is why we pay the"cost" to use e.g. functions "with care"(like avoiding wrong construct like aFunc(++i,i++) or potentially wrong like aFunc(&a,&a)) considering it normal or acceptable,while for macros we use a different judgement?I see no reason,but I accept the fact that other people may think there are reasons to consider macro more dangerous than anything else the language provide.Just PoV.

Answer (score 2):

While, I wouldn't advise this because it makes code confusing and less readable (without actually simplifying things), there is nothing technically wrong with it. If used correctly, it should not cause any problems or unintended behavior. Of course, if strange arguments are given as mentioned in one of the other answers, problems will arise.

Comment: And if someone writes a `loop` function, he will not be happy either.

Answer (score 1):

It's not LIKELY to be dangerous, but if used improperly, it could do something other than what you expect. The thing is that macros are doing TEXT replacement - they get to have a go at the code before the parser sees it. That means that if you do something in 'i' that has side effects, then whatever you've done will be replicated 3 times, and that might not be what you want.

If you always use it with simple variables, it'll always work correctly, but if you get complicated, you better be careful.

I personally wouldn't use it because I agree that it doesn't simplify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be avoided just because we have to think twice of potential side effects before using it. And so will the next programmer working on that code...